# Windows Hello. Remove Pin button is missing

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-10-v1709, windows-hello

Windows 1709.

[image]

Does anyone know which GPO controls the option/button "Remove" PIN?

The issue is I can setup the pin but if I forget it I cannot change it anymore as it asks the previous one. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't find such settings. please run command "gpresult /h c:\gpresult.html" to export the group policy settings, let's see if we can find any clue. Share the file on Network drive for me.

Comment: Thank you! but i managed to solve it.
Settings -> Accounts -> Access Work or school -> disconnected the current  "Work or school account" and by adding it again it allowed to setup new pin. So it was not GPO controlled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by going Settings -> Accounts -> Access Work or school -> disconnected the current "Work or school account" and by adding it again it allowed to setup new pin. So it was not GPO controlled.